# How to store a password?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, encryption, password-encryption

I have made a login page in jsp.

The username and the password are stored in mysql.

I want some suggestion for encrypt the password, and later decrypt the password(to verify if what is in password label equal with what is in database for that username).

Comment: You don't "encrypt" passwords. You hash them.

Comment: There are multiple articles in google about this for example http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/.

Comment: I try to encrypt or decrypt a text via Data Encryption Standard (DES) mechanism, but don't work because my SecretKey always changing. But hash the password like in exemple from above link work.

Comment: Never encrypt a password it is not secure enough. Always use a hashing function. There shouldn't be anyway to obtain the password from the hash. Use the latest hashing functions MD5 is not secure anymore. In fact you can find the plain text for many MD5 encrypted words by simply searching the hash on google. For login compute the hash and compare it with the stored hash from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before saving the password to database use hashing(MD5 or SHA256) and store the hashed value in database table.

While logging in, take the user password and hash it again using same technique and match with the hashed password stored in database table for this particular user. If these two hash values match then it is the correct password else the password does not match.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt and decrypt the password only if it is necessary (for example you want to check 3 of 6 pw-digits).

If you just want to check the password save the hashcode and just compare the hashcode.

Have a look on MD5, here a source snippet:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
```